# What signal is sent when you close a bash terminal to the programs it was running

Tags: bash, signals

I have a Bash script that launches a Python program. The Bash script handles `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` and `SIGHUP` signals to do a cleanup operation. I noticed that when I close the process in a tab in LXTerminal, the cleanup process happens. But when I close the entire terminal window, the cleanup process closes.

What am I missing to have the cleanup process to happen?

Comment: Have you tried using `strace`?

Comment: OP says the script handles `SIGHUP`; however **`SIGHUP`** is what I see when testing this.  Lacking a script to demonstrate the problem, there's nothing to test.

Comment: The process is probably "closing" because it gets a I/O error when still trying to read or write to the terminal **after** receiving the SIGHUP informing it that the terminal has been torn up and is no longer usable.

Comment: also see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491626/why-does-closing-terminal-emulator-window-terminate-a-bash-process-with-sighup-t/491650#comment902939_491650

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that *generates a script* that will try to catch all signals.  The script it generates (`sigcatcher.sh`) outputs the name of the caught signal before exiting.

```
#!/bin/sh

# generate a shell function for each and every available signal.

/bin/kill -l | tr ' ' '\n' |
while read signal; do
    cat <<END_OF_FUNCTION
handle_$signal () {
  echo "Caught $signal"
  exit
}

trap 'handle_$signal' $signal

END_OF_FUNCTION
done >sigcatcher.sh

echo 'echo "$$"; sleep 600' >>sigcatcher.sh
```

On my system (OpenBSD), `/bin/kill -l` generates a list of available signals on one line, that's why the `tr` is there to break it up.

The generated script will look something like this:

```
handle_HUP () {
  echo "Caught HUP"
  exit
}

trap 'handle_HUP' HUP

handle_INT () {
  echo "Caught INT"
  exit
}

trap 'handle_INT' INT
```

(etc.)

And it will be finished off with

```
echo "$$"; sleep 600
```

It outputs its PID and sleeps for 10 minutes.

You run it like this:

```
$ sh ./sigcatcher.sh >sigcatcher.out
```

Then you close the window, and then you inspect `sigcatcher.out`.

I don't run X Windows, but when I kill the `tmux` pane that this script is running in, I get "Caught HUP" in the output file.