# Why does closing terminal emulator window terminate a bash process with SIGHUP trap changed not to terminate?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, terminal-emulator, sighup

In a bash shell in a terminal emulator window of lxterminal, I run

```
$ trap "echo hello" SIGHUP 
$ kill -s HUP $$
hello
$
```

and then I close the terminal emulator window.

Does closing the terminal emulator window only cause SIGHUP sent to the controlling process i.e. the bash process?

Since the SIGHUP trap doesn't terminate the bash process, I expect the bash process isn't terminated, but why is the bash process actually terminated?

Same thing happen if I change the trap to `""` (ignore).

Terminal emulator matters. In bash running in a xterm window, setting trap to `""` will make a xterm window not closable, while setting trap to `echo hello` can still close a xterm window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ I'll ignore the actual and possible behavior of different terminal emulators; a completely reasonable behavior would be to send a `^D` (`VEOF`) to the pty on a window close / `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`, instead of tearing it down and causing the process running in it to receive a `SIGHUP`; the following assumes **`xterm`**, which will send a `SIGHUP` to the shell's process group in that case ].

The behavior you're seeing is because of the `readline` library, which is installing its own signal handlers. If you try the following:

```
xterm -e bash --noediting
```

(or `dash`, `zsh` or `ksh` instead of `bash --noediting`), then run

```
trap 'echo HUP' HUP
```

in the terminal, the window will become unclose-able; the shell will just print `HUP` as expected on trying to close the window; forcefully closing it (eg. with `xkill`) will cause the shell to exit with `EIO` errors, which is completely expected, since the pty was torn down.

Here is a simpler testcase for the behavior you're observing, not involving terminal emulators. Run  the following in your terminal:

```
bash --rcfile <(echo 'trap "echo HUP" HUP')
```

Then `kill -HUP $$` will just print `HUP`, but `(sleep 1; kill -HUP $$) &` (or `kill -HUP <pid>` from another window) will cause the shell to print `exit` and exit, unless you started it with `--noediting` (= don't use readline)

The `readline()` function as called by `bash` will install its own signal handlers upon waiting for input from the user, and restore the original handlers upon returning; a `SIGHUP` while waiting for input from the user will cause it to return `NULL`, which will be treated as `EOF` by `bash` (in the [`yy_readline_get()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?id=6c6454cb18d7cd30b3b26d5ba6479431e599f3ed#n1450) function), before having the chance to run the deferred trap handler.

Comment: Thanks. Is readline library a shared library? Does bash dynamically linked to it or dynamically load it by `dlopen()`?

Comment: Is closing a terminal window an  event which can generate SIGHUP? If that were true, how can setting up SIGHUP handler prevent the terminal window from closing, given that the terminal window is already closed?

Comment: 1. readline may be a shared lib, but on my system bash is linked statically to its own version of it 2. that's what xterm does when the user tries to close the window -- it sends a `SIGHUP` itself to process group of the terminal, and it won't actually destroy the window and the pty until the process started in it exits of its own volition.

Comment: other terminal emulators like mlterm or lxterminal will just close the pty, which will cause the kernel to send a SIGHUP; but even if the shell running in the pty ignores or handles that sig, it will die with EIO errors when trying to read from, write to or do termios ioctls on the slave part of a pty with no master.

Answer (score 5):

Bash also exits when it runs out of input to read. That can happen several ways, common ones being reading the last line of a shell script, the user typing control-D, or... closing the terminal window.

(You could also try `bash -i < /dev/null` and note how it immediately exits, because it ran out of input).

Comment: Thanks. When bash is waiting with a prompt, but there is never any input, how does it know it is not running out of input?

Comment: Does "Bash also exits when it runs out of input to read" happen not by signal? (ctrl-D doesn't send a signal?)

Comment: @Tim because the kernel treats the cases differently. If you read from a terminal/pipe/character device/etc. and there is no input available, your program just waits in the `read` syscall until either there is, or there is affirmatively not going to be any more. (There are a bunch of syscalls that handle reading/writing to files/devices, way beyond what can be covered in a comment, it's also possible to check the status without waiting). Typically this doesn't involve signals at all.

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot more happening under the covers than just a SIGHUP.  For example, closing the terminal window also causes the pty to be closed, so any output or input will return I/O errors.

We can see this by running `strace` on the `bash` process when you close the window.

We start with the `bash` process waiting at the prompt (the `pselect()`) and then close the window...

```
% strace -p 1090
strace: Process 1090 attached
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3409, si_uid=500} ---
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
ioctl(2, TCXONC, TCOON)                 = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7ffe1d1734e0)        = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

We're starting to see the I/O errors as `bash` tries to process the handler...

At this point notice that bash decided to shutdown because it has no control terminal, so it restores all the signal handlers and sends itself another SIGHUP

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x467410, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, {sa_handler=0x4bb540, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x466f10, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, {sa_handler=0x4bb540, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x4640e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, {sa_handler=0x4bb540, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x4676d0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, {sa_handler=0x4bb540, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x466f00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, {sa_handler=0x4baaa0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fe5c31b3060}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
getpid()                                = 1090
kill(1090, SIGHUP)                      = 0
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1090, si_uid=500} ---
```

And then the close down process continues (rewriting `.bash_history` and so on).

So it's not the initial SIGHUP that terminates the shell, it's the loss of the pty providing a terminal for input.

Comment: Interestingly, here those ioctls succeed — probably a different terminal emulator (I use xterm). Even writing the "exit" word succeeds here (`write(2, "exit\n", 5)                   = 5`)

Comment: Could be a timing issue, different version of bash, and so on, but the result is the same; eventually bash sees an error and gives up :-)