# Bash ` &` behaviour inconsistent when there's a loop at the end of the script

Tags: bash

When I start up Linux Mint 19, I like to launch a few things.  So I've been using a script (`./get-to-work`) in a MATE Terminal window to launch them all at once:

```
chromium-browser --start-maximized &
thunderbird &
code -n path/to/my/workspace &
```

That works great.  I launch the script, close the terminal window, and the three programs continue running.

However, I recently added a line to open a big yellow window every five minutes (to remind me to sit up straight):

```
chromium-browser --start-maximized &
thunderbird &
code -n path/to/my/workspace &
for i in {1..1000}; do sleep 300 ; xterm -bg yellow -g 240x80 ; done
```

Now if I close the terminal I launched this in, the script is still running, and it gets killed, and then I don't get any yellow popups.  That's actually a feature for me--I keep the terminal open as long as I want popups, and close it, for example, when I'm screen-sharing.

For whatever reason, though, closing the terminal and killing the script not only stops the popup loop, it now closes Chromium and Thunderbird too.  VSCode (`code`) stays open.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What happens in the first case:**

After the last command in the script is backgrounded, the shell executing the script exits immediately. This shell process was the parent process of the 3 programs started from the script. Now that their parent process has exited, the PID-1 process (`init` or `systemd` often nowadays) becomes their parent process.

The link between the terminal and the programs started from the script is gone, because the terminal program is not their (grand)parent process anymore.

**What happens in the second case:**

After the last backgrounded process, the script stays alive to run the loop. When the terminal exits, it sends SIGHUP to its child processes; the shell being its child, propagates this signal to its child processes (your programs).

The default action when a process receives a HUP signal is to exit. Apparently  `VSCode` ignores SIGHUP, or `fork()`s away from its parent process, so it is not affected.

Comment: Note: [`nohup thunderbird &`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618) should make the difference in the 2nd case.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski or better [`(trap '' HUP; thunderbird &)`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481033/308316)

Comment: In the first case, they're not receiving a SIGHUP because their process group is [not the foreground process group in the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491172/308316), *not( because the terminal emulator is no longer their grandparent. You can easily check with `xterm -e sh -c 'sleep 3600 &'` -- the sleep will be killed by SIGHUP despite it being adopted by init.

Comment: In the second case, resending SIGHUP is something very specific to `bash`, other shells don't do that (only *sleeping* background processes will be sent CONT + HUP *by the kernel*). Also, [only `xterm` is sending a `SIGHUP`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491993/308316) to the fg process group in the terminal -- most other terminal emulators will just close the master side of the pty, causing a `SIGHUP` to be sent by kernel.

Comment: It's interesting that the `nohup` and `trap` tricks both don't seem to work for keeping Chromium open, but they do keep Thunderbird going.

Comment: @Kev any program (eg. chromium) may reset the SIGHUP handler to default (ie terminate). Try running it as `setsid chromium &` instead.

Comment: @mosvy Indeed, that works!  Great to know!  :)