# How bash sets tty attributes before and after running a command?

Tags: bash, tty, pty, stty, pseudoterminal

Open `xterm`, run `tty` and see pseudo terminal slave file (let's say it is `/dev/pts/0`).
Then open another `xterm` and run

```
$ stty -F /dev/pts/0
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
lnext = <undef>; discard = <undef>; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel iutf8
-icanon -echo
```

Then run `/bin/sleep 1000` in first xterm. Then run the same `stty` command in second xterm again:

```
$ stty -F /dev/pts/0
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel iutf8
```

Then terminate `sleep` command in first xterm. Then run the same `stty` command in second xterm again:

```
$ stty -F /dev/pts/0
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
lnext = <undef>; discard = <undef>; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel iutf8
-icanon -echo
```

We see that bash changes tty attributes before running a command and restores them back after running a command. Where is it described in bash documentation? Are all tty attributes restored, or some attributes may not be restored if they are changed by program?

Comment: have not yet fully grasped what you demonstrate. Just a first remark: using stty on a PTY terminal is probably a complicated experiment. X windows will be controlling some of the TTY settings. "tty attributes" are likely to be spread out a bit. stty has limited effect and precision here.

Comment: "We see that bash changes tty attributes..." I turn it around: by putting bash to sleep, the status of that terminal is changed and maybe even adapted by xterm -- put to "standby".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the `readline(3)` line-editing library, which is usually statically built as part of bash, but is also used by other programs.

Every time it starts reading a command from the user, readline saves the terminal settings, and puts the terminal into "raw" mode [1], so it could be able to handle moving the insertion point right and left, recall commands from the history etc. When `readline(3)` returns (eg. when the user has pressed Enter), the original settings of the terminal are restored. Readline will also mess with signals, which may result in some [puzzling behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491650/308316).

If you strace `bash`, look for `ioctl(TCSETS*)` (which implements `tcsetattr(3)`) and for `ioctl(TCGETS)` (`tcgetattr(3)`). Those are the same functions used by `stty(1)`. If you run bash with `--noediting` you will see that it leaves the terminal settings alone.

[1] not exactly the "raw" mode of `cfmakeraw(3)`; you can see the exact details [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/rltty.c#n236). All those terminal settings are documented in the `termios(3)` manpage.