# Why does SIGTERM work to terminate bash but not ash or dash?

Tags: linux, shell, signals, dash, ash

Comparing `bash`, `ash` and `dash`, only `bash` can be terminated by `SIGTERM`

```
kill -TERM <pid>
```

For `ash` and `bash`, I need `SIGHUP` or `SIGKILL`

```
kill -HUP <pid>
kill -KILL <pid>
```

What's the reasoning behind this? Furthermore, the behavior seems to be system-dependent:

- `bash` is terminated by `SIGTERM` on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan, Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, Debian 8 Jessie, Debian 9 Stretch, Debian 10 Buster, CentOS 8
- `bash` is *not* terminated by `SIGTERM` on CentOS 6, CentOS 7

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals: "When Bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores SIGTERM (so that ‘kill 0’ does not kill an interactive shell) ..." So did you kill an interactive shell or a script?

Comment: If I simply run `bash` in my terminal emulator, isn't that an interactive session? That's what I killed by running `kill <pid>` (inside another terminal emulator).

Comment: Shells are generally made to terminate when receiving the `HUP` ("hang-up") signal, not `TERM`.

Comment: I could witness OP's behaviour on Debian9 and Debian10's or CentOS8's bash, going against the relevant information in the man page. Works as expected (not killed) on CentOS7

Comment: @A.B. It has rather to do with the bash version than with the distro it runs on. Also, it has to do with readline installing its own signal handlers -- `bash --noediting` will not be killed by an `SIGTERM`. Nor will bash kill itself by running `kill -TERM $$`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491650/308316) for something similar.

Answer (score 4):

This only happens when bash is using the `readline` line editing library, and only when `bash` is waiting for input from the user.

A `bash --noediting` will not be killed by `SIGTERM`, nor will `bash` kill itself if running `kill -TERM $$`.

This happens because the `readline()` function used by bash to get input from the user, will install its own signal handler for `SIGTERM`, and restore the original signal disposition before returning. If a `SIGTERM` happens while `readline` is waiting for input from the user, `readline()` will return `NULL`.

The bash function which calls `readline()` (`yy_readline_get()`) will interpret a `NULL` return as `EOF`, causing the shell to exit. The scenario is quite similar to that from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491650/308316).

This means that an interactive bash could be also made to survive a `SIGTERM` by setting `IGNOREEOF` ;-):

```
$ bash
$ IGNOREEOF=10
$ echo $$
11096
<kill -TERM 11096 from another terminal>
$ Use "exit" to leave the shell.
<kill -TERM 11096 from another terminal>
$ Use "exit" to leave the shell.
...
<the 10th will get it>
$ exit
$
```

Answer (score 3):

This was unexpected to me, but doing a couple of builds revealed it was reproducible on bash's latest code from git, but not bash 4.0. As such `git bisect` was helpful in pinpointing the following commit as being responsible:

```
% git bisect good                     
ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961 is the first bad commit
commit ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961
Author: Chet Ramey <chet.ramey@case.edu>
Date:   Wed Feb 26 09:36:43 2014 -0500

    Bash-4.3 distribution sources and documentation
```

Bash's individual git commits tend to be fairly large and not super tightly scoped, but spending a few minutes going through that commit shows a number of changes to how readline handles SIGTERM, including a new rl_signal_event_hook which SIGTERM is supposed to bypass, and plenty of new places that we check for SIGTERM and call `termsig_handler`.

Part of those changes matches up with this new entry in in the changelog:

> Readline calls an application-set event hook (rl_signal_event_hook) after it gets a signal while reading input (read returns -1/EINTR but readline does not handle the signal immediately) to allow the application to handle or otherwise note it.  Not currently called for SIGHUP or SIGTERM.

Judging by this message, I believe the change in behaviour may not be intentional.

I'm going to forward this thread to the bug-bash mailing list in the hopes of getting to the bottom of whether this was intentional or not.

Comment: For future reference, this is the thread on the `bug-bash` list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-03/msg00006.html